# angular controller - $filter sortBy integer

Tags: angularjs, filter

My data is being sorted as a string:

```
ID          Name
1122162089  John McGill
1461        Cynthia Salazar
22925       Sylvan Knutsen
24930       Amrit Advani
```

I need to sort it as a number

```
var sortedData = function (records,optionsData) {
    var sortField = optionsData.sort[0].field;
    var sortDir = optionsData.sort[0].dir !== "asc";
    var tempRecords = $filter('orderBy')(records, sortField, sortDir);

    return tempRecords;
}
```

where

```
sortField = "ID" and sortDir = "asc"
```

Haven't figured out how to write a custom filter condition **in the controller**.

What's strange is that ID is numerical in the data:

```
[{
    ID: 1122162089,
    Name: "John McGill"
},{
    ID: 1461,
    Name: "Cynthia Salazar"
}]
```

Comment: where is ng-repeat? in your post? do update it to help you further

Comment: There is no ng-repeat. This is in the **controller**. That is one of the things that frustrates me so much - every example assumes it's in the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is being sorted as a string most likely because the ID is a string. You can add a custom comparator to the $filter to handle the string IDs. Also you can access the orderBy filter by injecting orderByFilter into your controller like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', function($scope, orderBy)
```

Then you can use the orderByFilter like this to sort your data with a custom comparator:

```
var sortedData = function(records, optionsData) {
    var sortField = optionsData.sort[0].field;
    var sortDir = optionsData.sort[0].dir !== "asc";

    var tempRecords = orderBy(records, sortField, sortDir, function(val1, val2) {
        var v1 = parseInt(val1.value);
        var v2 = parseInt(val2.value);

        if (v1 === v2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return v1 < v2 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });

    return tempRecords;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the **controller** solution, not the VM solution that others have offered.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I use orderBy in an table, look this example. You have to put the element what you want to order in "expression", and "reverse" is how the data will be show, ascending or decreasing, with true for decreasing and false for ascending.

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in usuarios | orderBy : expression : reverse">

</tr>
```

If the problem with string hold on, try using parseInt().

Comment: No. **Controller**, not VM.